# WinSCP "lcd .\" command ends up in C:\WINDOWS\system32 when executed in VBA, instead of user profile folder like when executed manually

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, sftp, winscp

Trying a simple file download from an SFTP server by calling a batch file from Excel VBA. Here's the bat:

```
@echo off

".\WinSCP.com" ^
/log="C:\Users\User\Documents\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
 /command ^
    "open sftp://user:password@site.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 4096 y+key=""" ^
    "cd /" ^
    "lcd .\" ^
    "get file.TXT" ^
    "exit"

exit
```

The script runs perfect if I run the bat manually but if called from VBA it doesn't execute.

I've tried:

```
Set oSHELL = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
exitCode = oSHELL.Run("""C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Folder\Folder Name Has Spaces\sftp.bat""", 0, True)
If exitCode <> 0 Then
  MsgBox "Failed to download TN1!", vbCritical, "Failure"
Else
  MsgBox "Downloaded successfully", vbOKOnly, "Success"
End If
```

and also, simply:

```
Call Shell("""C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Folder\Folder Name Has Spaces\sftp.bat""", 0, True)
```

Edit: I pointed it to the `program files (x86)` `winscp.com` file and it generated a log. The `lcd .\` is pointing to a restricted folder (`system32`):

```
> 2021-05-21 10:54:10.918 Script: lcd .\
< 2021-05-21 10:54:10.918 Script: C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

How can get around this? I cannot use an absolute file path because it will be different for different users based on their user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lcd .\` does nothing! If the batch file works, when you run it manually, it's only because the batch file is started in the right working directory from the beginning, not because of the `lcd .\`.

If you want to work in `syncfolder` subfolder of the current user's profile folder, no matter, where the batch file is executed from, use:

```
    "lcd ""%USERPROFILE%\syncfolder""" ^
```